# Matlab: Plots and Subplots - How do I make Matlab zoom into all the subplots simultaneously?

Tags: matlab, zooming, subplot

I have multiple sub-plots. When I zoom into the first subplot to view a certain data set Matlab does not zoom the rest of the subplots. How do I make Matlab zoom into all subplots simultaneously?

```
subplot(2,1,1)
hold on
plot(Tim1.in,IA1.raw32SPC,'b-')
hold off

subplot(2,1,2)
hold on
plot(Tim1.in,IA1.cos,'r-*')
hold off
```

Comment: See [`linkaxes`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html), and [`linkprop`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkprop.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `x` variable is the same, It makes sense to just link the `x` axes in this case. I added some code to create the `x` and `y` variables so that anyone can run the code below. You were also using hold unnecessarily.

```
x = 1:10;
y1 = 3*x;
y2 = x.^2;
ax(1) = subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x, y1, 'b-')

ax(2) = subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x, y2, 'r-*')
linkaxes(ax, 'x')
```